# Show attribute widgets even if the Add to Cart form only represents one product

Tags: commerce

I'm having problem with display option, of Product variation field as "Add to Cart form":

[image]

With that option it should show variation switcher, **whenever there is one or more product variations**.

But it does not:

[image]

Simply looks like "Show attribute widgets even if the Add to Cart form only represents one product." option doesn't change anything.

The above display shows teasers on the front page (I have trying manipulating default view in Manage Display as well).

I have trying clearing cache, running cron and changing my customized *node--product--type.tpl.php* and *node--product--type--product--list.tpl.php*  to oryginal ones and it does not help as well.

Comment: Do you have any attributes set up on your products? That is, fields which are marked in their field configuration as being attributes that will show up on the add to cart form?

Comment: I'm not quiet sure what you'r talking about :). I have couple of additional fields for product displays and it's variations. Hovewer I just want to show in teaser product variation switcher so it is set to display in teaser in product display and product variation display settings.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things you have to ensure you do right for this to work, as even in my little test environment to reproduce the error I screwed it up a couple different ways.

1. You must ensure the field you've added to your product type has checked the box to state that it should function as an attribute field on Add to Cart forms.
2. You must edit the field display settings using the form you've posted a screenshot of, but make sure you save the full form as the "Update" button on the expanded form doesn't actually save any changes to the database.
3. You must reproduce that for all relevant view modes.

With all of those things in mind, I was actually able to confirm the feature itself is working as advertised when properly configured:

[image]

Comment: I did 2, 3, however where do I set a variation switcher field to be an attribute field on Add to Car form?

That switcher simply does not show when there is only one product variation, in default view and any other like teaser.

Comment: It's a field setting, actually. Edit the field and look for the checkbox regarding Add to Cart form behavior.